# Why does `./gradlew allureServe` command gives empty report on Allure Gradle?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradlew, allure

I have tried to integrate Gradle with Allure and I run the command "./gradlew allureServe" after I have done all previous configurations. I even run the tests on which I am supposed to get a report on and I get always empty report.
Can someone explain exactly what does "./gradlew allureServe" command do?
Where does it get the information which is shows in the browser as a report?
Attached you can see how my report looks like each time I run the command.

[REPORT ALLURE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zFcfp.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try `./gradlew build` and `./gradlew test` before executing the `./gradlew allureServe`. The test cases might have not been executed. The report is generated from the `build/allure-results` folder.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! I fixed it and the problem was what you suggested.